# What caused Geordi La Forge's blindness?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Geordi La Forge was blind from birth.  Do we have any material in the novels or other sources which indicates what specific medical condition caused this congenital blindness? Is it a medical condition we have today, or some kind of space medical condition (like an alien infection)?

Answer (score 61):

A genetic condition of some sort.  In ["The Masterpiece Society"](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/213.htm) Geordi discusses this with a member of the genetically "perfect" society

> HANNAH: Were you always blind?
>
> LAFORGE: I'm sorry. I probably shocked the hell out of you, didn't I?
>
> HANNAH: No.
>
> LAFORGE: I'll put it back on.
>
> HANNAH: Don't. I'm sorry. I didn't mean to embarrass you.
>
> LAFORGE: I've never been embarrassed by this, Hannah. Never. I was
> born blind. I've always been this way.
>
> HANNAH: May I see it? Your visor?
>
> LAFORGE: Sure. So, I guess if I had been conceived on your world, I
> wouldn't even be here now, would I?
>
> HANNAH: No.
>
> LAFORGE: No, I'd've been terminated as a fertilised cell.

I think this discussion implies that there was some genetic cause, rather than a pre-birth infection or injury.

Comment: I don't think just implies.   It states it.   There's no way for the state of a single fertilized cell to result in blindness except via the genetic route.  Even if there were some pathogen involved, it would still have to cause blindness by altering genetics.

Comment: @ThePopMachine, It wasn't expressly stated, and you reached the conclusion through logic. It was therefore implied. Even if you're right about only being one logical conclusion, that doesn't mean it's not implied.

Comment: @ThePopMachine epigenetics?

Answer (score 26):

There's no canon material that ever explains why LaForge is blind. The only things we know about his blindness are

1. He was born that way (TNG: [Encounter at Farpoint](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/101.htm))

   > CRUSHER: You've been blind all your life?
   > LAFORGE: I was born this way.
2. It had something to do his optic nerve (TNG: [All Good Things...](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/277.htm))

   > CRUSHER: This is amazing. The DNA in his optic nerves is regenerating. Geordi, it's as if you're growing new eyes.

Memory Alpha [notes this](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Geordi_La_Forge#Apocrypha)

> The computer game Star Trek: The Next Generation - The Transinium Challenge establishes that Geordi's blindness was caused by an "incurable optical nerve defect."

That [video game](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_-_The_Transinium_Challenge) is not canon, but it is consistent with the canon mentions above.

Comment: strictly speaking, if it's *re*generating, that implies that it was good at some point and then deteriorated. of course, regenerating DNA wouldn't change anything about the functionality of the nerves anyway...

Comment: Hey, maybe "regenerating" here is a transitive verb without a direct object. The DNA is engaged in the general act of regenerating its surroundings, much as I could be eating.

Comment: @ths: I think it's very plausible to interpret "regenerating" as the gene(s) returning to a working form that the variant he inherited was copied from with errors.

Comment: The concept of "DNA regenerating" doesn't make much sense either as the thing being regenerated or the thing performing the regeneration. To me it just sounds like technobabble written by someone who doesn't understand biochemistry.

Comment: What's weird is that - if it was just his optic nerves, then his eyes would look perfectly normal from the outside even if they weren't functional.  But instead, his eyes are milky-white with no visible corneas or pupils, which is an entirely different kind of blindness.  I guess they wanted to have some visual cue to show the audience that he's blind.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman:  It's actually pretty reasonable to assume that defects in the iris and cornea could be corrected with the technology of TNG (many cases already can) -- they are essentially just mechanical and optical which is physics not biology.  So it's possible the genetic defect does affect all three, but it's only the defect in the optic nerve which is the incurable part.

Comment: @WaterMolecule I can think of a few instances where the Star Trek writers demonstrated that they did not really understand biology or genetics.

Comment: @SethR I am shocked, I tell you. [Shocked](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Threshold_(episode))!

Comment: For what it's worth, there's a real genetic defect where you could be born without malformed or non-existent eyes ([Branchiooculofacial syndrome](https://disorders.eyes.arizona.edu/handouts/branchiooculofacial-syndrome)).  It looks like all the other symptoms are ones that can be corrected with (possibly extensive) surgery, so if Geordi's particular defect let the eyeball itself form without any other structure (or if they were surgically implanted as placeholders), it's close enough to be believable. And it could mean that there just _wasn't_ a nerve to attach anything to.